# Vim: automate reading line from external file

Tags: vim, vimrc

I am trying to automate the following in vim:

```
:r! sed -n 10p filename
```

Where the line number (10) is constantly changing. I was thinking something along the lines of

```
function! GetLine(line, filename)
    :r! sed -n a:line,p a:filename
endfunction
```

which I have put in my .vimrc and properly sourced. But when I call with `:call GetLine(10, "testfile.txt")` it doesn't work.

Now, while I have been using vim for quite a while, I am new to scripting it, so please bear with me if I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this

```
function! GetLine(line, filename)
    execute 'r! sed -n ' . a:line . 'p ' . a:filename
endfunction
```

`execute` executes the following ex command. We generate the ex command using string concatenation. `.` concatenates strings and variables

Take a look at `:h :execute`

Comment: This has exactly the functionality I was trying to generate. Very good to know about `execute` and `.`

Answer (score 0):

A different approach more suitable to a mapping is inserting the line number via `<C-r>`:

```
:nmap <Leader>r :r! sed -n <C-r>=variable<CR>p filename<CR>
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but how would I call this again? I'm curious, as this may be more what I was looking for in the first place...

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a full example mapping. I hope this makes it clear.